# How to fix lag on dual display Wayland?

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors

I am having way too much trouble after trying to ditch Windows.

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 with ubunt-drivers. The display laggs way too much on both displays, when it is set to Joined Display or External mode. The inbult laptop monitor runs on 1920x1080x60.01Hz, the external one runs on 1920x1200 59.95Hz, which may be the problem. Using DisplayPort by the way. Sadly the monitor has no HDMI :(((

I also tried to use Xorg instead, but the external monitor was not recognized at all.

Any recommendations to do? It's currently unusable as a daily driver.

Forgot to mention that the laptop has Intel HD, MX150 and using the external monitor with a Graphics Dock (GTX 1050). Unfortunately, I was not able to try to connect directly to the laptop, as it has no DisplayPort connections.